# Starting shell from android app to run separate executable

Tags: android, process, runtime, executable

I want to start shell from android application because i want to run an executable file and pass few arguments and expect output.

I tried ProcessBuilder and process and run at runtime listening to their io stream but android app does not allowing me to start shell is this permission issue??

I am getting all the time

> runCommand error: Error running exec(). Command: [su] Working Directory: null Environment: null

Is there a way to run shell as an interface between running app as a process and process will be started from shell?

Shed some light on this issue thanks

Answer (score 1):

Actually, when you use the "su" hack what you are getting is a shell that runs as root (if the device has been modified to support that)

If you don't want a root shell but an ordinary one running as your application's userid, you could presumably run /system/bin/sh or whatever it is on your device instead of su.

Comment: @himanshu Additionally, you cannot execute programs stored on the sdcard

Comment: If i put it underneath the subdirectory of the project it would not able to find that every time do you know what is wrong?

Comment: Underneath the subdirectory of the application is pretty much the only place you can put it.  You will have to use api calls to identify what that directory is in a particular installation.

Comment: Command: [/data/data/mypackage/executable/ffmpeg] Working Directory: null Environment: [-vcodec copy, -i /mnt/sdcard/download/sample.m4v, -ss 00:00:00, -t 00:02:00, /mnt/sdcard/download/output/partone.m4v] this is what happening every time i am getting path like getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("mypackage", PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES).applicationInfo.dataDir or srcDir

Comment: In your package's private directory, with the execute bit set is the only location likely workable at present, but even that is not officially supported, as android does not officially support 3rd-party executables, period.  external storage, assets, etc definitely do not work.